# How to generate UUID without dashes (hyphens) in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, uuid

When generating a **UUID** in Laravel, It's being generated according to the standard format which includes 4 dashes (hyphens) like this (for example):

```
51a0cb84-8b3d-43c4-bfd4-8fcef1f360d4
```

How to generate the UUID in Laravel without dashes or hyphens? like this:

```
51a0cb848b3d43c4bfd48fcef1f360d4
```

Comment: Don't change raw format of data (thank me later), better make some helper function which you can use accross application to compare nonDashedUuid with uuid. `if (customHelperMethod($uuidString, $nonDashedUuidString)) { /** do the job */ }`.

Comment: @Tpojka Thank you. I will take this into my consideration.

Comment: Thing is that all other packages that you'll face in the future consider uuid as is and you'll spend so much time to adapt all of those to use your™ string but for nothing of gain imho. Instead use it how it should be used - like industry standard and if you need some modification do it outside any general use. Read S.O.L.I.D. and pay double attention of O.

Answer (score 6):

In Laravel (since version 5.6), you can generate a UUID (version 4) that follows the standard format using the [`Str::uuid()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-str-uuid) method:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return Str::uuid();
```

Or, to generates a "timestamp first" UUID that may be efficiently stored in an indexed database column, you may use [`Str::orderedUuid()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-str-ordered-uuid):

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return Str::orderedUuid();
```

And because Laravel actually makes use of [`ramsey/uuid`](https://github.com/ramsey/uuid) package to generate the UUID, then generating the UUID in Laravel without dashes or hyphens could be done using the package's [`getHex()`](https://github.com/ramsey/uuid/issues/97#issuecomment-174196026) method:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return Str::uuid()->getHex();

// OR
return Str::orderedUuid()->getHex();
```